# sprite kit centering on main character issue

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have been trying to get a camera working in sprite kit to work from the documentation. when i am calling the centerOnNode method in didSimulatePhysics my character is still moving on the screen and not staying in the center. can anyone suggest what i am doing wrong. I have seen a similar issue on here but have been unable to spot what i am doing wrong, i am new to sprite kit.

```
    @implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake (0.5,0.5);//centralise the scenes anchor point
        //self.size = CGSizeMake(1000,1000);

        //create a world node to represent the scrolling world
        SKNode *myWorld = [SKNode node];
        [self addChild:myWorld];

        SKNode *camera = [SKNode node];
        camera.name = @"camera";
        [myWorld addChild:camera];

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"character.png"];
        sprite.name = @"player";
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        [myWorld addChild:sprite];

        SKAction *myAction = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(50, 50) duration:7];

        [sprite runAction:myAction];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didSimulatePhysics{
    [self centerOnNode: [self childNodeWithName: @"player"]];
    }

- (void) centerOnNode: (SKNode *) node{
    NSLog(@"in centerOnNode");
    CGPoint cameraPositionInScene = [node.scene convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];
    node.parent.position = CGPointMake(node.parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x,
                                       node.parent.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y);
    }

@end

    enter code here
```

Comment: And where is your camera node?

Comment: sorry, i have now created this just after creating and adding my world node. i have edited the code in my quesiton above but it is still not working, it doesn't work when i pass @"camera" to the centerOnNode function either

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution i needed. I was not pulling in the camera and player nodes into didSimulatePhysics and then setting the camera nodes position to the player nodes position. The following example achieves what i wanted but if anyone has a better way of doing this please suggest:

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake (0.5,0.5);//centralise the scenes anchor point
        self.size = CGSizeMake(2000,2000);//make scene bigger to see if world scrolls

        //create a world node to represent the scrolling world
        SKNode *myWorld = [SKNode node];
        myWorld.name = @"world";
        [self addChild:myWorld];

        //create a camera node
        SKNode *camera = [SKNode node];
        camera.name = @"camera";
        [myWorld addChild:camera];

        //create two sprites, one with a moveTo action
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"character.png"];
        sprite.name = @"player";
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        [myWorld addChild:sprite];//add sprite to world node

        SKAction *myAction = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(500, 500) duration:10];
        [sprite runAction:myAction];

        SKSpriteNode *sprite2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"character.png"];
        sprite2.name = @"player";
        sprite2.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+50, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+50);
        [myWorld addChild:sprite2];//add sprite to world node
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)didSimulatePhysics{
    //pull in camera and player sprites
    SKNode *camera = [self childNodeWithName: @"//camera"];
    SKNode *playr = [self childNodeWithName: @"//player"];
    //position camera where player is
    camera.position = CGPointMake(playr.position.x, playr.position.y);
    //center world on the camera
    [self centerOnNode: camera];
}

- (void) centerOnNode: (SKNode *) node{
    CGPoint cameraPositionInScene = [node.scene convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];
    node.parent.position = CGPointMake(node.parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x,
                                       node.parent.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y);
    }
@end
```

Comment: Also does anyone know why we need to use @"//camera" and @"//player" instead of @"camera" and @"player"? what does the // mean?

Comment: my guess is thats because camera is not child of the scene. Camera is child of the world which is child of the scene.